# Use bubbling to affect outer div (HTML, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

In short: How do you utilize bubbling so that clicking inner div elements affects the outermost div element?

**HTML**

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B>
        <div class="C"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it so that when the user clicks an inner div, or the outermost div for that matter, the outermost div is brought forward together with the inner divs. Together, the divs represent a "window" on the screen. There will be several windows of this kind (with the same structure and classes) and more can be generated after page load.

What is good practise? How many eventlisteners do I need? What should the JavaScript look like and do I need to change anything in the HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably only need one eventlistener on the outer element, and bubbling happens all by itself when someone clicks

Comment: There can be multiple outer elements with the same classes (multiple windows) and more added after page load. Are you saying I should add one listener on every outer element?

Comment: Also, listening on the outer div didn't work the first time I tried, but I can try again.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/rzbL5880/1/ to see how you can use a single event to handle each nested `div` differently

Answer (score 0):

You only need one event listener for the outermost div **unless** you want a click within an inner div to behave differently, in which case you could use `stopPropagation()` to stop the action from 'bubbling' up the chain any further.

[MSDN has an example of this here](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/ie9_event_phases.htm).

Comment: Note that there will be several outer divs of the same kind, some added after page load. Do you mean I should add listeners on all of them?

Comment: @Candleout I'm not sure what you mean by several outer divs "of the same kind"? And can you add what you've tried that didn't work to your question?